# why are the arrows missing on the read thod docs theme

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I've created documentation using Sphinx and the read the docs theme, but the arrows are missing from the buttons

Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the css files of sphinx theme are located in the right place

Comment: Thanks. solved. I had the _static directory in my .gitignore file. This contains the css

Answer (score 0):

Your Sphinx document probably uses CSS that specifies a font, in which these unicode "codepoint boxes" are arrows.

Either the CSS is external, but not shipped alongside with the HTML, or so is the font.